# Multiple specific Divs by drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, mootools

I'm at the bottom of the loaded `<iframe>` products you want to drag the individual `<div>` are at the top of the screen. At the top, on demand as pictured on the size of the frame will be from 1 to 5 `<div>`s and the background right frame.

When you are finished adding products to your frame and you click on a key or mouse button to jump to the basket and completion order.

Please help which way to go. jQuery UI or maybe Mootools? And the easiest way to do this.

Comment: You might consider jQuery UI's `droppable`: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

Try this amending the code in this page. It is based on moving DIVs but could be amended for your requirements by just changing the DROP function. Note that the example you show isn't ideal as it doesn't highlight where you are allowed to drop objects, whereas this one does.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">

.box {  width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;}

.obj {  width: 220px;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;}

#dragApp {background: #bbffbb;}

#dragAny { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    top: 10px;
    background: #ffbbbb;}

#dragBox { 
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background: #bbbbff;}

#dragFlt { 
    position: static;
    float: right;
    background: #ffcc0f;}

.closeBox {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -6px -6px 0px 6px;
    padding: 8px 2px 10px 2px;       
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #eebbbb;
    background: #dd8888;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;}

.closeBox:hover {
    color: #ffdddd;
    background: #ee6666;}

</style>

<script>

function ge$(d) {
    var x = document.getElementById(d);
    if (!x) {
        var y = document.getElementsByName(d);
        if (y.length>0) x = y[0];
    }
    return x;}

function winScrollX() {
    var x = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
    return x;}

function winScrollY() {
    var y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    return y;}


function addEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
    if (elem.addEventListener)
        elem.addEventListener(eventType,handler,false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent)
        elem.attachEvent('on'+eventType,handler);
}

function removeEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
    if (elem.removeEventListener)
        elem.removeEventListener(eventType,handler,false);
    if (elem.detachEvent)
        elem.detachEvent('on'+eventType,handler);
}

function stopBubble(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    if (evt.stopPropagation)    evt.stopPropagation();
    if (evt.cancelBubble!=null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
}

function stopDefault(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
    evt.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}


var dragObj = [];
var dragBox = [];
var dragApp = [];
var dragItm = '';

setDrag = function(idObj, idBox, appChild) {
    if (dragObj.indexOf(idObj) == -1) {
        var obj = ge$(idObj);
        obj.draggable = true;
        addEventHandler(obj,'dragstart',drag_start,false);
        addEventHandler(obj,'dragend',drag_end,false);
        obj.style.cursor = 'move';
    }
    if (dragBox.indexOf(idBox) == -1) {
        var box = (idBox == 'body' ? document.body : ge$(idBox));
        addEventHandler(box,'dragover',drag_over,false); 
        addEventHandler(box,'drop',drag_drop,false); 
    }
    var i = dragObj.length;
    dragObj[i] = idObj;
    dragBox[i] = idBox;
    dragApp[i] = !!appChild;
}

function drag_start(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    this.style.opacity = 0.33;
    dragItm = this.id;
    var offsets = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("Text", (offsets.left-evt.clientX+winScrollX()) + ',' + (offsets.top-evt.clientY+winScrollY()));
    evt.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
}

function drag_end(e) {
    this.style.opacity = 1.0;}

function drag_over(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    var idObj = dragItm;
    var idBox = (evt.currentTarget == document.body ? 'body' : evt.currentTarget.id);
    var fnd = false;
    for (var i=0, len=dragObj.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (dragObj[i] == idObj && dragBox[i] == idBox) {
            fnd = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fnd) {
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
        stopDefault(evt);
        stopBubble(evt);
    } else {
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
    }
}

function drag_drop(e) { 
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    var idObj = dragItm;
    var idBox = (evt.currentTarget == document.body ? 'body' : evt.currentTarget.id);
    var fnd = false;
    for (var i=0, len=dragObj.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (dragObj[i] == idObj && dragBox[i] == idBox) {
            fnd = true;
            var app = dragApp[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fnd) {
        var obj = ge$(idObj);
        if (app) {
            evt.currentTarget.appendChild(obj);
        } else {
            var params = evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text").split(',');
            obj.style.position = 'absolute';
            obj.style.left = (evt.clientX + parseInt(params[0],10)) + 'px';
            obj.style.top = (evt.clientY + parseInt(params[1],10)) + 'px';
        }
        stopDefault(evt);
        stopBubble(evt);
    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(value) {
        for (var i=0, len=this.length; i<len; i++) {
            if (this[i] === value) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

function closeBox(obj) {obj.style.display = 'none';}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>

<div id="dragApp" class="obj">This one appends to either box.</div>
<div id="dragAny" class="obj"><div class="closeBox" onclick="closeBox(this.parentNode);return false;">X</div>This one can be dragged anywhere.</div>
<div id="dragBox" class="obj">This one can only go in the top box.</div>

<p>I decided to look into HTML5 drag and drop. I found several examples online, but none seemed to 
provide any validation of where the items were being dragged except when they were actually dropped. 
So I created this page as an example of how to do it.</p>

<div id="dragFlt" class="obj"><div class="closeBox" onclick="closeBox(this.parentNode);return false;">X</div>This float goes in the bottom box.</div>

<p>Note that the example built into this page won't work in IE9 as I've set DIV elements to drag, 
but IE9 only supports IMG and A-HREF elements.</p>

<p>I wrapped the whole thing in a setDrag function that takes in the ids of the object to be dragged 
and the location where it can be dropped. If the drop is to be completed by appending the object as a 
child then a third argument should be set to true.</p>

<p>There are seven events involved in dragging and dropping:</p>

<pre>
object      dragstart   when object first moved
        drag        while object is being moved
        dragend     when the object is dropped

target      dragenter   when object enters the target
        dragover    while object is over the target
        dragleave   when object leaves the target
        drop        when the object is dropped
</pre>

<p>The dragstart/dragend events are useful for changing the object appearance, and for initialling the 
cursor types and obect data in dataTransfer. The drag event isn't used here.</p>

<p>I don't use the dragenter/dragleave events. The drop event is the one that handles the moving of the 
object by changing its position/DOM location. The key is the dragover event as this determines where a 
drop can actually be made. The default is to not allow a drop so unless it performs a stopDefault() then 
no drop will be allowed.</p>
<br>

<p>There are some <b>gotchas:</b></p>

<p>In IE dragover can't use either THIS or dataTransfer to access the object info. So to get the id of 
the object in dragover you need to set a variable in dragstart.</p>

<p>In object events you can use event.target for the object (same as THIS) but in target events you have 
to use event.currentTarget (same as THIS) instead.</p>

<p>FF doesn't need to initialise the effectAllowed but IE does. I'm not use if setting the cursor to 'none' 
is required or not.</p>

<p>Because of event bubbling (I think) you still need to validate the combination of object/target in the 
drop event.</p>

<script>
setDrag('dragApp','box1',true);
setDrag('dragApp','box2',true);
setDrag('dragAny','body');
setDrag('dragBox','box1');
setDrag('dragFlt','box2');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, there seems to me to Use HTML5 was a good option. Firstly, I do not know whether you can use elements of Action as well in jQuery. Secondly jQuery cope with most browsers - HTML5 is the problem, unfortunately, problems with browsers. You can leave a jQuery object source in the same position as in the example, but in HTML5 found no such possibilities.

In addition, unless the same HTML5 does not give us as full control over the Shares to throw a cookie has been kept in the sessions, go to the basket with the values ​​transferred boxes.

If I am wrong, please correct me.